# Getting the difference in milliseconds between two dates to be used in counter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a counter library that will count down the amount of time allowed for user for reading a book section, that library will accept a milliseconds value to work.

Now i have function for getting the allowed time from api which contain the following code :-

```
// api request -> var data.created_at = contain the section read request created_at date/time.

      var readAllowedurationInHr = 2;
      var readAllowedDurationInDay = null;
    
      var createdAt = new Date(data.created_at);
    
        if (readAllowedDurationInDay) {
          createdAt.setDate(createdAt.getDate() + readAllowedDurationInDay);
          var diffInMilliseconds = createdAt.getTime() - Date.now();
        }
        if (readAllowedurationInHr) {
          createdAt.setDate(createdAt.getHours() + readAllowedurationInHr);
          var now = new Date();
          var diffInMilliseconds = createdAt.getTime() - now.getTime();
        }
    
        setCounterValue(diffInMilliseconds);
```

The code for getting the days difference "if (readAllowedDurationInDay)" is working, but for handling the hour difference "if (readAllowedurationInHr)" it show in the counter a count down starting from 16 days.

How can i get the difference in hours between dates in millisecond unit ?

Comment: You have milliseconds. You can perform a simple math to convert it to `hours` right ?

Comment: @Panther, the counter accept a millisecond value in order to show a count down where it can start from, not in a hours unit

Comment: I think you are mis-understanding. A simple (date1 - date2) will result in a number which is the difference in milliseconds. Use a simple math to convert this to your desired unit.

Comment: @Panther, you are right, i can see that my error with difference is from createdAt.getHours() + readAllowedurationInHr it returned in console log Jul "Jul 22 2020 20:34:17" the orginal created at value is "Jul 05 2020 20:34:17", the code added 16 days to createdAt date instead of 2 hr